# How to satisfy trait bounds when making this function generic?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I've been using the image-rs (0.23.12) library to implement some basic image analysis functions, by way of learning Rust (I come from a Javascript/Python background). I access pixel data through an iterator that image-rs provides for that purpose. Here is a minimal example of a function that accepts a reference to an image sub-region (`image::SubImage`) and iterates through the pixels within it, making a comparison with each.

(Playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=extern%20crate%20image%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ause%20image%3A%3A%7BGenericImageView%2C%20SubImage%2C%20ImageBuffer%2C%20Luma%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20grey_image%20%3D%20ImageBuffer%3A%3Anew(300%2C%20200)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20subimg%20%3D%20grey_image.view(100%2C%20100%2C%2020%2C%2020)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20find_dark_pixels(%26subimg)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afn%20find_dark_pixels(img%3A%20%26SubImage%3C%26ImageBuffer%3CLuma%3Cu8%3E%2C%20Vec%3Cu8%3E%3E%3E)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20WHITE%3A%20Luma%3Cu8%3E%20%3D%20Luma(%5B255%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20pixel_iter%20%3D%20img.pixels()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20pixel_iter.any(%7C(_%2C%20_%2C%20pixel)%7C%20pixel%20!%3D%20WHITE)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Found%20dark%20pixels!%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D))

```
extern crate image;

use image::{GenericImageView, SubImage, ImageBuffer, Luma};

fn main() {
    let grey_image = ImageBuffer::new(300, 200);

    let subimg = grey_image.view(100, 100, 20, 20);
    
    find_dark_pixels(&subimg);
}

fn find_dark_pixels(img: &SubImage<&ImageBuffer<Luma<u8>, Vec<u8>>>)
{
    static WHITE: Luma<u8> = Luma([255]);
    let mut pixel_iter = img.pixels();
    if pixel_iter.any(|(_, _, pixel)| pixel != WHITE) {
        println!("Found dark pixels!");
    }
}
```

(`image::Luma` is a monochrome pixel.) This non-generic version of the function compiles and runs just fine. It does, however require the argument to be a `SubImage` and nothing else. Not very useful - it really needs to operate on either a whole image or a subset of one, as needed. The trait that allows this is `GenericImageView`, and both Image and `SubImage` implement it.

My first attempt was to change the function signature to:

```
fn find_dark_pixels<I: GenericImageView>(img: &I)
```

which elicits this from the compiler:

```
binary operation `!=` cannot be applied to type `<I as GenericImageView>::Pixel`
the trait `std::cmp::PartialEq` is not implemented for `<I as GenericImageView>::Pixel` rustc(E0369)
```

The pixel types in image-rs do implement `PartialEq`, so I told the compiler so:

```
fn find_dark_pixels<I: GenericImageView>(img: &I)
    where <I as GenericImageView>::Pixel: std::cmp::PartialEq
(the rest is unchanged)
```

It then complains that 'pixel' in the closure and 'WHITE' have mismatched types:

```
mismatched types
expected associated type `<I as GenericImageView>::Pixel`
            found struct `Luma<u8>`
consider constraining the associated type `<I as GenericImageView>::Pixel` to `Luma<u8>`
for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html rustc(E0308)
```

I followed (I believe?) the compiler's suggestion and changed the function signature to:

```
fn find_dark_pixels<I: GenericImageView>(img: &I)
    where <I as GenericImageView>::Pixel: Luma<u8>
(the rest is unchanged)
```

The compiler counters with:

```
expected trait, found struct `Luma`
not a trait rustc(E0404)
```

At this point, I tried annotating 'pixel' and 'WHITE' in various ways, but I consider myself stumped. You know, and I know, that Luma implements everything needed for the comparison `pixel != WHITE`, but I don't know how to convince rustc.

(If it helps, it's OK for the function to only work with `ImageBuffers` of type `Luma<u8>, Vec<u8>` - I only need to work with monochrome images. But it does need to work with any (immutable) image view.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: I believe the compiler's suggestion about "constraining the associated type" wants you to do `fn find_dark_pixels<I: GenericImageView<Pixel = Luma<u8>>>(img: &I)`.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler's suggestion about "constraining the associated type `<T as Trait>::Associated` to `Concrete`" means that you need to request a concrete type for the associated type directly in the trait bound. This is done with the `Trait<Associated = Concrete>` syntax - e.g. to constrain `I` to an iterator that produces strings, you'd write `I: Iterator<Item = String>`. In the case of `find_dark_pixels` you'd request the `Pixel` associated type to be `Luma<u8>` as follows:

```
fn find_dark_pixels<I: GenericImageView<Pixel = Luma<u8>>>(img: &I) {
```